# Are there disadvantages to spaced repetition?

Tags: memory, spaced-repetition

[In his essay Michael Nielsen](https://augmentingcognition.com/ltm.html) talks about his way of learning about new field of study. He's using spaced-repetition to remember things he learned. It seems that he adds a lot of information into his system.

Example of two questions he adds to his system, after reading one paper is

> "What does Jones 2011 claim is the average age at which physics Nobelists made their prizewinning discovery, over 1980-2011?” (Answer: 48)
>
> “Which paper claimed that physics Nobelists made their prizewinning discovery at average age 48, over the period 1980-2011?” (Answer: Jones 2011)

Are there any disadvantages from trying to remember so much information? I don't mean the obvious ones like time it takes to create cards / test them.
I think I read somewhere that there is a tradeoff between memory flexibility and amount of information you can learn but I can't find it now.

Comment: It seems this article lists some disadvantages from reviewing the research, I apologize this is not peer reviewed https://www.gwern.net/Spaced-repetition